# 14.04 Live USB stick can't install nodejs

Tags: live-usb, ruby, nodejs

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a USB stick, and I'm trying to get my Ruby on Rails dev environment setup.

I'm having trouble installing nodejs. I used the method:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
```

Which is fine, but when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

I get:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends: rlwrap but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

So I found this:
ttp://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.docker.user/201

So I ran this:
    sudo echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

But I get:
    bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied

I tried a couple of other things, which you can see here (scroll to near the bottom):
https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/problems-following-odot-tutorials-using-local-install-pc

But nothing has worked. One of the mods on Treehouse is at a loss now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: It worked! Thankyou ever so much! For those who are curious, I made a ubuntu 14.04 live usb (with persistence) and followed this: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html but used the above instruction to install nodejs.